# Scala-JS for real web project

Tags: scala, playframework, client-side-validation, scala.js

Has someone used `Scala-JS` in real web project but not only for plain `JavaScript` replacement in isolated env ?

I would like to use Scala as much as possible (I wish I could). And seems `Scala-JS` claims to be that lib I could use (now) or in the future.

That's why I'm interested in small working solution to look at, to bootstrap (like `PlayFramework` app  where `Scala-JS`).

The solution/example that could demonstrate that `Scala-JS` can be used in real web-development work.

I'm asking because [what I found](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/tree/master/examples) about `Scala-JS` so far is hardly real usage of it.

Q: some examples / proves that It is ready to use in real project?

**UPDATE (after 1 year):**

There are tons of examples for `TypeScript` for example.. That what I mean when I said "examples" and "real web projects". And there many online trainings. And if I query in Google: "typescript github angular", it returns **172 000 pages**. `ScalaJS` has lack of all it definitely and unfortunately.

But it has some: ' "scala-js" github angular ' - **4 980 matches**. But so far most of it is "early stage of development" with "no commercial support"

That one seems promising: https://github.com/greencatsoft/scalajs-angular

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I haven't seen client-side form validation specifically, yet. However, there are several projects that use Scala.js effectively, among which:

- [A basic setup with PlayFramework](https://github.com/vmunier/play-with-scalajs-example), where client-side JS is written in Scala.js
- [A more significant example with PlayFramework](https://github.com/sjrd/scala-js-actors/tree/master/examples/chat-full-stack) essentially demonstrating the Scala.js actors proof-of-concept
- [Other projects written in Scala.js](http://www.scala-js.org/#built_with_scalajs) but with nothing to do with Play, but that demonstrate Scala.js' power to varying degrees.
- [Roll](http://lihaoyi.github.io/roll/), probably the most significant Scala.js project so far.

Comment: There is also https://github.com/hussachai/play-scalajs-showcase

Answer (score 16):

I just noticed this question, and should probably chime in -- as mentioned above, my company's product, [Querki](https://www.querki.net/help/#documentation), has its UI now built entirely in Scala.js. That's about 8k SLOC of Scala, last I checked: not the biggest program in the world, but a lot more complex than most sites. I would guess that it's replacing what would have been 20-30k SLOC of JavaScript, and is really the only way the company is plausible at all.

That's beta for a small company, but very much in production, and it's been a godsend: the SJS code is *vastly* easier to write and maintain than the JavaScript it replaced, and much more stable in practice. Also, hooking the SJS front end up to my Akka/Play back end speeds up development enormously, and reduces bugs, since the API is strongly-typed and boilerplate-free, in end-to-end Scala.

Since folks have asked: the optimized JS code is currently about 1 Meg, and growing quite slowly now that all my infrastructure is written. (Plus about as much again for the JS libraries I use.) That's not trivial, but it's a one-time load per release; once it's cached in the browser, the UI is *extremely* fast, much quicker than the dynamic pages that had been there.

Oh, and since you're looking for a fully-worked example: the source code can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/jducoeur/Querki). That's open-but-restricted, since it's a commercial product, but feel free to dig around and use it for inspiration. (And feel free to request useful bits out of it: I'm gradually lifting broadly-useful bits and pieces into MIT-licensed libraries.)

Comment: Yep.  One additional point, though -- Scala.js interoperates with existing JS infrastructure better than folks usually expect.  Querki is the poster child there: I'm using [something like a dozen open-source jQuery libraries](https://www.querki.net/help/#Credits-for-3rd-Party-Components), and it turns out to be easier to use jQuery from SJS than from JavaScript...

Answer (score 9):

I am actively building a [dashboard webapp](https://github.com/yakticus/scalajs-dashboard) for my startup using scala.js. It is incomplete, but evolving quickly.

My initial prototype was based on angular.js, using the [angulate bindings](https://github.com/jokade/scalajs-angulate). I later replaced angular with a reactive-style mesh of [scala.rx](https://github.com/lihaoyi/scala.rx), [scalatags](https://github.com/lihaoyi/scalatags) and [scalacss](https://github.com/japgolly/scalacss), which is takes advantage of the scala type system. All the logic/rendering is type safe and in one language (scala), rather than being spread across "stringly-typed" HTML, CSS and JavaScript

Although this webapp is being developed as an internal tool, it should be able to demonstrate scala.js in a real world application once it's finished.

Comment: Is that done? ) Trying it with scalarx as well.

Comment: The web app is functional with some working examples. I also started an SVG visualization library for scala.js (using D3 under the hood). You can find it here: https://github.com/yakticus/goggles

Answer (score 6):

Then

1. W3C uses it in banana-rf: github.com/w3c/banana-rdf
2. @jducoeur builds Querki : github.com/jducoeur/Querki
3. TypeSafe shares a very substantial template: typesafe.com/activator/template/play-scalajs-showcase

All of the above demonstrate rather advanced features & techniques.

The careful reader can learn a lot and determine for himself it ScalaJS is [ready for prime time](http://scala-lang.org/news/2015/02/05/scala-js-no-longer-experimental.html).

Lastly, this https://github.com/SemanticBeeng/play-scalajs-showcase is a derivative of the original showing how to apply event sourcing and functional domain models to move from a CRUD oriented API to a functional API.
This is an experiment and work in progress.

Comment: I like this: https://github.com/greencatsoft/scalajs-angular and this https://github.com/greencatsoft/scalajs-angular-todomvc as examples. I also put UPDATE to my question.

Comment: With the current client we are developing a loans management application with ScalaJS and it goes smoothly. The only serious issue is the large size  of the generated JS file. We use SJS essentially because it enables DRY business logic (not so much to replace native JS). We still write the client with TypeScript and use Durandal.

Comment: @SemanticBeeng can you share the approximate size of the generated JS vs the equivalent hand-written JS? Even a rough constant factor would be very helpful.

Comment: @pkinsky The un-optimized generated code is in the MBs. But please realize I'd compare apple seeds with orange jam if I was to compare hypothetical JavaScript code (which I do not have) with the generated SJS JavaScript code... SJS is a Scala backend (not a translator; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138601/what-is-the-difference-between-scala-js-vs-jscala) and, as such, it generates JavaScript code equivalent to Scala code using the (almost) full power of the Scala language. You would never look at that code so size is only relevant for loading in browser.

Answer (score 4):

More recently (2016), you have [**sri** (Scala React interface)](https://github.com/chandu0101/sri).

It is a scalajs library to build truly native cross platform (mobile (ios and android) and web) applications.
It is based on [reactjs](http://facebook.github.io/react/) and [react-native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/).

Use this module to build browser based applications:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.github.chandu0101" %%% "sri-web" % "0.6.0"
```

Comment: I like where it is going. hope it will not leg behind original js-react (speaking of scalajs-react).

Answer (score 1):

The official Scala.js homepage lists projects built with Scala.js: http://www.scala-js.org/community/

Comment: Those ones look more like ads than as projects..

Answer (score 1):

ThoughtWorks's TodoMVC application with the help of [Binding.scala](https://github.com/ThoughtWorksInc/Binding.scala) and [Scala.js](http://www.scala-js.org/):

- [Project Page](https://github.com/ThoughtWorksInc/todo)
- [DEMO](https://thoughtworksinc.github.io/todo/)

I don't know if it is a real web project because it seems unreally concise. The DEMO contains only **one source file, 147 lines of code**, while the ReactJS implementation of the same TodoMVC feature took 488 lines of code.